# Opencart Custom mysql search form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, opencart

I am creating a simple custom search form. This form searches the table 'oc_product' where i created a new column 'gcode'. I have inserted a sample data in this column for one of the products. Is it necessary to make a new db/mysql connect in php within a new tpl file i created just like 'information/contact'. I call this 'gcode/gcode'.
I tried but unable to get result form the search. It redirected to index.php.
My code is:

```
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  id="searchform"> 
   <input  type="text" name="name"> 
   <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
</form>


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){
  if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name'])){
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  //connect  to the database
  $db=mysql_connect  ("localhost", "username_demo",  "pwddemo123") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
  //-select  the database to use
  $mydb=mysql_select_db("db_demo");
  //-query  the database table
  $sql="SELECT * FROM oc_product WHERE gcode LIKE '%" . $name .  "%'";
  //-run  the query against the mysql query function
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  //-create  while loop and loop through result set
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          $gcode  =$row['gcode'];
  //-display the result of the array
  echo '<span>'."This product is genuine".$gcode.'</span>';

  }
  }
  else{
  echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
  }
  }
  }
```

Any example to search a column and fetch data from a column.

Comment: I guess I don't need to tell you you shouldn't be using mysql_ stuff anymore right? problem seems to be with `if(isset($_GET['go']))`... you have defined a 'post'on your form declaration, not a 'get'. try just removing this condition

Comment: Yes Julio that was correct i removed the isset function and kept it on _POST and that worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand your question. Do you want to fetch data from ONE column? Also use  mysql_fetch_assoc instead mysql_fetch_array
And replace $_GET with $_POST
Also your select statement is wrong, so do this:

```
<?
$sql="SELECT * FROM oc_product WHERE gcode LIKE '%$name%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$results = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i=0; $i<$results; $i++)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$gcode = $row['gcode'];
// Here list it the way you want
echo $gcode.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oc_product
            WHERE (`gcode` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error()); I further modified a bit

Answer (score 0):

you would need to create a model or simply add this field in the search model to be searched by it. i am not sure if that is what you want to accomplish, also you would want to make sure to sanitize the request and escape it before you get one of the SQL injection attacks.

Comment: ya tried but it was too complex for me to understand the opencart search structure as i had shortage of time. however i did make a custom tpl file with controller and database fetching to be in normal php with search 'like' sql function, so atlast have got it working this way.